# How would I render my MUI drawer on all components except login page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am trying to render the Material UI drawer on all pages except the login page but it's not working accordingly.

**In short**

1. My App component has 2 routes login and dashboard (Both Working)
2. Then my dashboard page has multiple routes for home and about pages (None of them working.)

Below is my code separately. Also, I'm attaching codeSandBox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-tereshkova-9fpmw?file=/src/App.js) for the same

**Expected Output To understand my desired output**

```
On login URL = <Login/> should render

On dashboard URL = <AppDrawer/> should render

inside AppDrawer I am having more routes in
<main>
<Route path="/home" component={home}/>
Route path="/about" component={about}/>
</main>
```

My actual code is here:
**App.js**

```
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import AppDrawerBar from "./compponents/AppDrawerBar";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={AppDrawerBar} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Login.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Login = () => {
  return <h1>Login Page</h1>;
};

export default Login;
```

**AppDrawerBar.js**

```
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from "@material-ui/core";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";
import Home from "../pages/Home";
import About from "../pages/About";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  hide: {
    display: "none"
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: 0
  }
}));

export default function PersistentDrawerLeft() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Persistent drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
        open={open}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === "ltr" ? (
              <ChevronLeftIcon />
            ) : (
              <ChevronRightIcon />
            )}
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["All mail", "Trash", "Spam"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <main
        className={clsx(classes.content, {
          [classes.contentShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />

        // More Routes for main pages

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
  return <h1>Home Page</h1>;
};

export default Home;
```

**About.js**

```
import React from "react";

const About = () => {
  return <h1>About Page</h1>;
};

export default About;
```

Comment: What is it that is not working exactly?

Comment: @tmarouane, Please check In short I've told my issue there :-)

Comment: Thanks, checked and answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mainly missing two steps to get your router working and updating your main content:

1. Propagate route change upon items click: The side `Drawer` component should be wrapped with a `Router` component and individual `ListItem`s should be declared with `Link` as their component so whenever an item is clicked on the side menu, the change is propagated.
2. Updating your main content based on the navigated route: The `main` element should make use only of `Route` components to have the content dynamically loaded upon URL location change.

Here down the updated `AppDrawerBar` component (note that I omitted the redundant `ListItem`s to bring focus to the important changes:

```
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar
          position="fixed"
          className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
            [classes.appBarShift]: open
          })}
        >
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="open drawer"
              onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
              edge="start"
              className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
              Persistent drawer
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer
          className={classes.drawer}
          variant="persistent"
          anchor="left"
          open={open}
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper
          }}
        >
          <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
            <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
              {theme.direction === "ltr" ? (
                <ChevronLeftIcon />
              ) : (
                <ChevronRightIcon />
              )}
            </IconButton>
          </div>
          <Divider />
          <List>
            <ListItem button key="home" to="/home" component={Link}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <MailIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Home" />
            </ListItem>
          </List>
          <Divider />
          <List>
            <ListItem button key="about" to="/about" component={Link}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <InboxIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="About" />
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Drawer>
        <main
          className={clsx(classes.content, {
            [classes.contentShift]: open
          })}
        >
          <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
          <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </main>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
```

### Edit:

The `Link` component mentioned above is the one from *react-router-dom* since it will redirect to the new */home* and */about* locations allowing the `main` directive content to update accordingly.

Here you can find [a forked (working) copy of your `AppDrawerBar`](https://codesandbox.io/s/routing-with-drawer-forked-cbblk?file=/src/compponents/AppDrawerBar.js) component.

Comment: He alredy have the `history` context because he used `BroswerRouter` on `App.js`

Comment: Thanks @Melvynx for pointing that out. Shall update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @tmarouane I appreciate your efforts. But unfortunately, it's not rendering my home and about components. Check codesandbox  here https://codesandbox.io/s/routing-with-drawer-9fpmw?file=/src/compponents/AppDrawerBar.js

Comment: Hey @user9824674, sorry for the confusion I should have made it more clear although the explanation would have helped you: You should use the `Link` component from *react-router-dom* and not from *material-ui*. Re-edit and re-check.

Comment: Thank you @tmarouane. sooo much I'm so grateful to you for helping me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I saw you use `react-router` so if you want your drawer is displayed all the time except on the login page you can simply add conditional render for your drawer using the `useHistory` hook from "react-router-dom".

```js
const history = useHistory
console.log(history.location.pathname) // give the current path name
```

[image: location pathname exemple]

So here is a solution :

```
export default function PersistentDrawerLeft() {
  const history = useHistory(); // from react-router-dom
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      {history.location.pathname !== "/login" && 
     <>
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Persistent drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>

        <Drawer
          className={classes.drawer}
          variant="persistent"
          anchor="left"
        open={open}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === "ltr" ? (
              <ChevronLeftIcon />
            ) : (
              <ChevronRightIcon />
            )}
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["All mail", "Trash", "Spam"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
     </>
    }
      <main
        className={clsx(classes.content, {
          [classes.contentShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />

        // More Routes for main pages

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is such a nice way to do it. But you're just hiding the side drawer I want to hide this complete component inlu8cing appbar. So I tried to use multiple switches one in app.js to two-parent component login and appdrawerbar. Since, appdrawerbar is also a parent component containing other pages component so I tried Switches here. It's like nested routing "dashboard" route render appdrawerbar. "dashboard/home" route render home component inside appdrawerbar

Comment: You just need to move my conditional block to wrap the `AppBar` and the `Drawer` with `React.Fragment`

Comment: I've edited my answer to match with your preferences.

Comment: If I can provide you an advices: Do not mix the UI with the Routes, creates seperates components for your routes!

Comment: Thanks, that was needed. I'll try to separate my routes